# Is it possible to temporarily ignore tests in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Our test suite often breaks because we run a lot of integration tests against external services not in our control. When those external services face service interruptions, our builds begin failing.

Is there a way I can temporarily ignore a test in Jenkins (during an external service interruption) so that it doesn't look like the whole build isn't broken which it actually isn't.

Comment: You can break it down into smaller jobs, where the integration tests against the external services are each triggered independently downstream. This way you'll have more granularity over where the failure is.

Comment: Why not move your whole test suite as a separate job so you can disable it temporarily? Making your jobs a little bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [Jenkins Quarantine Plugin](https://github.com/samsta/quarantine) allows users to temporarily quarantine tests. I have been in the same situation than you and this plugin most certainly is a life-saver!

**But** the project isn't really maintained. As you can see, its build status is "Failing" today, probably due to the recent Jenkins API changes.

---

**However**, the plugin has been working well for me with the following configuration:

- Jenkins 1.526
- Quarantine Plugin built from SHA [2c8393d4c21106c4e4f7f3868e8fc19509aee884](https://github.com/samsta/quarantine/commit/2c8393d4c21106c4e4f7f3868e8fc19509aee884) as follow:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/samsta/quarantine.git && cd quarantine
  git checkout 2c8393d4c21106c4e4f7f3868e8fc19509aee884
  mvn clean install
  ```

---

I am sure you can find a way to make it work, so I hope you will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

You can split it into smaller chunks and trigger next jobs even if some of them failed.

Another way to do it, is to reconfigure your tests in a way they always return 0, but in case of a failure, they set some environmental flag. Then you can use Conditional Buildstep Plugin, and see if this flag is set or not, and based on flags from different tests you can assess if the job succeeded or failed at the end of job.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a service virtualization tool to emulate the responds of your service.  This way you decouple your dependence on a service you cannot control while running your tests.